Where is the mention of 28 names of Shri Radha?
Where in shastras is there mention of 28 names of Shri Radha which give whatever we desire either it be dharma/artha/kaam/moksha/Prem(love of God,5th purusharth in urdhvamanya tantra)

They are mentioned in Ṛgvedīya Rādhopaniṣat https://archive.org/details/HRTL_kalyan-upanishad-issue-no.-1-vol.-23-january-1949-gita-press/page/n725/mode/2up?view=theater
It seems though that there are two different texts with the same name Rādhopaniṣat.
One is shared by Gītā press, there's another which appears in Unpublished Upanishads https://archive.org/details/UnpublishedUpanishads-AdyarLibrary1938Edition/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater

Thanks, her name is "bhukti-mukti pradaini"which means she gives whatever we desire
